# Mixing ASP.net Identity and Azure AD authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity-2

We use ASP.Net Identity for our DB backed login currently and need to add support for Azure AD SSO.

I appreciate once logged in I will need to link the SSO user to a user in our system to assign the relevant Claims and Roles but am struggling to get the 2 authentication methods working side by side and app.UseCookieAuthentication seems to be at the root of my problems.

Currently we have:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Index"),
            ReturnUrlParameter = "url",
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, IdentityUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthenticationTimeout"])),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });
```

With this in I suspect the cookie returned by the SSO isn't getting processed correctly as the Request.IsAuthenticated is always false.

If I change it to:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

Then the SSO works and returns me an authenticated request but obviously breaks the Identity login.

For info my OpenId setup is as follows, for now just trying to get it to work with our work AD but eventually will need to expand to multi tenant:

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        );
```

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try using the

`app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);`

before

`app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`